# How to set margins to two div inside another div?

Tags: css, background-position

I want to set different margins to two divs, inside another div. The first div should appear top of the second div.

```
<div style="position:relative">
 <div style="position: absolute;margin-top:24px">
   This should be appar top of the second div.
 </div>
 <div style="margin-top:24px">
   second div
 </div>
</div
```

I used above mention code, but first div also getting `margin 50`, not `margin 24`.
How to resolve this issue?
Cannot use `position:absoulte` to the second div.

Answer (score 3):

enter this code  inside div

```css
margin: 5px auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
   <div style="position:relative">
     <div style="posiotion:absolute, top:24px">
       This should be appar top of the second div.
     </div>
     <div>
       second div
     </div>
   </div>
```